# What is your experience using 3rd-Party 10Gig Media Converters with Cisco equipment?

Tags: layer1, cable, 10gbase, utp, media-conversion

We have just received a device with 10Gig BaseT ports (for copper cable with RJ45 endings) that needs to be connected to a Cisco Nexus 5548. This switch only has SFP+ ports and we're connecting them right now using a couple 1Gbps SFP. We really would like to use the 10Gig connection.

I googled 10Gig Media converters and found some brands but i have doubts regarding stability and compatibility. The final scenerio would be like this:

[Nexus 5k]--[10G SFP+]---Optical Fiber Jumper---[Media converter]--Cat 6a--[DataDomain]

Does anyone out there have a similar combination of equipment? How has it worked for you?

Comment: That seems like a really wonky and overly complicated setup.  Is there a reason that you are using a media convertor?  Do Data Domains not have an SFP port or fiber NIC?

Comment: Hi Zack! You are right: it IS convolute. It is not my first choice but i am just exploring options. The problem here is that the DataDomain is already at my premises but came only with RJ45 10G ports.We will probably buy the DataDomain SFP+ port module but the buying process in our company is somewhat burocratic. I thought that maybe buying the media converter was cheaper enought to be a temporary option while we buy the right part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the obvious question is how much all that media converter stuff costs versus just buying a cheap 10G NIC with an SFP+ port and using fiber, twinax or AOC to achieve a sane and supportable result?  Will the converter work?  Sure - most likely... will it be supportable and stable?  It's definitely outside the realm of best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Third party SFPs can be hit or miss.  Make sure to check the compatibility matrix that cisco has.

If the module is an unsupported module then it will not work right off the bat.  There is a command to enable them, but a warning will pop up stating that Cisco doesn't recommend it and that they can't guarantee performance.  Also, if you choose to enable the Third Party modules via that command Cisco reserves the right to stop troubleshooting, if memory serves.

Comment: You are right about the 3rd party SFPs being hit or miss. I've found about some 10G SFP+ BaseT transceivers on the internet but i haven't found any feedback/reviews/commentary about them. I thought that maybe someone here may have experience with them or with Media Converter units. Guess everyone is having doubts about them as i do. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it costs more, but usually the easiest solution is to buy SFPs that Cisco approves of.  I've never dealt with 10g media converters so I can't speak to that, but many of the media converters on the market are utter garbage.

Comment: 3rd party stuff is definitely hit or miss but a third party 10GBaseT SFP+ is a few steps beyond,  There is a good reason Cisco doesn't sell such a beast on its own GPL - it draws way more power and generates much more heat than the port was built for.  Worst-case with a third party SR SFP+ is that it doesn't work.  Worst case with a 10G TX and you damage the switch.

Answer (score -1):

The third party components will work fine.  If you find otherwise, I would love to hear back...

Don't resell them as Cisco though.  People have gone to prison for doing so...

Also, if you tell Cisco TAC they will void your SMARTnet contract out.